SQL to Retrieve, for all Rows, the Sum of Values of Previous Rows By Time Series
My SQL is rusty.  I have a DataFrame/table like this (partially shown, and this is just a sample, not the real data):
+--------------------+-----+---+
|           timestamp|value| id|
+--------------------+-----+---+
|2024-10-05 20:38:...|   67|  0|
|2024-10-05 19:38:...|   14|  1|
|2024-10-05 18:38:...|   80|  2|
|2024-10-05 17:38:...|    6|  3|
+--------------------+-----+---+

What I want to do, in plain English, is this: suppose an id is in row 0.  I want get a result set of data such that for the id in row 0, I return the sum of all data in column value for all rows 3 hours before the timestamp in row 0, and including the value for row 0.  Then, I want to do this for all the rows, 0 through n (where n rows could be large, on the order of hundreds of millions).
So, my output would look like this (truncated a bit):
+--------------------+-----+---+
|           timestamp|sum  | id|
+--------------------+-----+---+
|2024-10-05 20:38:...|  167|  0| /* this result is the `value` of the id in row 0, plus the three hours' of previous data */
|2024-10-05 19:38:...|  100|  1| /* this would be more than 100 with the full dataset, etc. */
|2024-10-05 18:38:...|   86|  2|
+--------------------+-----+---+ /* etc etc */

I'm sure this question or a variant has been asked, but I've done a ton of research and I can't seem to find this.  To be more specific, I'm working with Spark DataFrames, but vanilla SQL is also fine.

Why is your question tagged [tag:mysql]? Are you using MySQL? MySQL is not the same as Apache Spark.

Filled it out a little fast.

In SQLite you could do
SELECT
  d.timestamp,
  d.value,
  d.id,
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(di.value)
    FROM data di
    WHERE
      di.timestamp BETWEEN datetime(d.timestamp, '-3 hours') AND d.timestamp
  ) AS sum
FROM data d;

Not really familiar with Spark but googling Spark DataFrames and "window functions" returns promising results
Something along the lines of
Window.partitionBy().orderBy(col("timestamp").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-10800, 0) seems the way to go

Yup this is it!  It turned out that the SQL you mentioned worked great.  probably could explore window functions a bit more, too.  Thanks.

Your helper here are window functions. I am not familiar with Apache Spark, but regarding the documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html) it should be working in this area like Postgresql.
In short, a window function does kind of a data aggregation without the grouping rows stuff, but with a window over which the operation is computed. If you are using e.g. sum, then with a provided order by you get a running sum or in your case an inverse running sum.
(https://sqlfiddle.com/postgresql/online-compiler?id=29dd419d-b12d-4b1c-8d02-72b8f728174d)
select 
ts, value, id,
sum(value) over (order by id desc) as sum
from dataframe order by id;

were sum(value) over (order by id desc) is a window function and delivers this result:



ts
value
id
sum




2024-10-05 20:38:00
67
0
167


2024-10-05 19:38:00
14
1
100


2024-10-05 18:38:00
80
2
86


2024-10-05 17:38:00
6
3
6




This is great; definitely helpful!!  The other answer turned out to be exactly what I was lookin' for but your answer was helpful; +1.

Good. However, I didn't took those 3 hours into account.
